# Cassandra Architecture on upsert

Tags: cassandra, bigdata

I was reading [this](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/dml/about_inserts) article about Cassandra upsert. It's [this image](http://www.datastax.com/docs/_images/update_db_12.png) shows 2 lines in `memtable` and `commit log` as follows.

```
k1 c1:v5 c4:v4
k1 c1:v2 c3:v3
```

What I want to know is if "`it's a mistake and 2nd line's k1 should be k2`" or "`it's not a mistake and talks about 2 consecutive updates on k1`" ?

Hope the question is clear.

I will have a 2nd question if the answer is `no, it's not a mistake`. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a mistake. It should show both k1 and k2.

While it is valid for the commit log to show k1 twice (for example from two different writes) the memtable would show one row in that case.

Comment: Thank you very much for the confirmation.